# lua script - end loop when socket connection is broken

Tags: sockets, while-loop, server, lua, client

I have a little Lua script thats run an socket (server).
when a client connects to the server socket then he can send multiple messages.

Now the problem is ..
For be able to receive at all time the messages from the client i put a while loop in my code.
But when a client disconnect because of internet problems, and he tries to reconnect then we get a new connection but if we send something we get nothing back.

I Think that it is because he is already in his loop when we connected with the first client.

Now my question is, is there a way that i can program the script so that the script knows that the client was disconnected and when he is disconnected that the while loops stops.

thx for the help !

```
socket = require("socket")
server = assert(socket.bind("*",9667))
tcp = assert(socket.tcp())


client = assert(server:accept())
keep = client:setoption("keepalive",true)
time = client:settimeout(1)
client:send("connection ok\n")


while true do 
  message = client:receive()

  -- if we get a 'off' message from the client --
if (message == "off") then
    client:send("off\n");


end

  -- if we get a 'on' message from the client --
if (message == "on") then
  grp.write('0/2/1',true)
    client:send(" on\n");


end
  log(message)
end
```

Comment: First of all, please fix the formatting of that code

Answer (score 1):

You can detect a closed error from your send and receive calls by taking the second value. You can then check the second value is closed and exit your loop.

```
socket = require("socket")
server = assert(socket.bind("*",9667))
tcp = assert(socket.tcp())


client = assert(server:accept())
keep = client:setoption("keepalive",true)
time = client:settimeout(1)
client:send("connection ok\n")


while true do
    message, err = client:receive()

    -- if we get a 'off' message from the client --
    if (message == "off") then
        _, err = client:send("off\n")
    end

    -- if we get a 'on' message from the client --
    if (message == "on") then
        grp.write('0/2/1',true)
        _, err = client:send(" on\n")
    end

    if err == "closed" then
        break
    end

    log(message)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help ! I tried it but it isn't working. When i replace me client:receive to you're example then i get no output anymore if i send a message. Also when i end my client and reconnect with another i have the same problem. There is connection but he is still in his while loop.

Comment: I over complicated thing by using pcall, I read over the documentation for luasocket and send/receive will pass an error message as the second value when it has an error. http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/tcp.html i revised my answer